# How to repeatedly add to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> using a loop and only one other ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java, and I want to have an ArrayList (mainList) of ArrayLists of Strings, with an unknown number sets of strings that can only be extracted as individual strings, not all together as a list.

My idea was to repeatedly append each string of a set to an ArrayList (list2), append list2 to the end of mainList, then empty the ArrayList, then append each string of the next set to list2, append that one, empty the list, repeat. I've included an example of what I tried to execute:

```
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();



for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){

     for (int j = 0; j < items.get(i).innerItem.size(); j++){

          list2.add(items.get(i).innerItem.get(j).string);
     }

     mainList.add(list2);

     list2.clear();
}
```

let's say that there are 2 items, having innerItem 1 with strings "haha" and "hehe", and innerItem2 with strings "chuckle" and "what"

mainList then has two lists in it, both of which are "chuckle" and what"

The mainList ends up having multiple lists of all the same array: the last list that was appended. The Clear function seems to clear both the list2 and the mainList section that was appended. How do I make it so that the lists stay different? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a sample input and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently add one single `ArrayList<String> list2` multiple times into `mainList` since it always stays the same object and it stays empty since you clear `list2` everytime you reach the end of the loop.

If I understand your question right your problem should be solved by using this code:

```java
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
     ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int j = 0; j < items.get(i).innerItem.size(); j++) {
          list2.add(items.get(i).innerItem.get(j).string);
     }
     mainList.add(list2);
}
```

Now a new ArrayList is created for each entry of your `items`-List and added to `mainList`

Answer (score 0):

`list2` is an object and, like all objects, acts like a reference type. What that means is if you append `list2` to `mainList`, and then clear `list2`, that will also clear the list you just appended to `mainList`. When you then change `list2` to hold other values, it will also change the content of the appended list within `mainList.`

In the end, you've appended `list2` a bunch of times, and each simply refers to the same memory address as the original `list2` object. As such, they are all the same.

To fix this, you can either create a clone of `list2` and append that clone rather than `list2` itself, or overwrite `list2` as a new list each iteration by construction.

Option 1:

```
mainList.add(new ArrayList<>(list2));
list2.clear();
```

Option 2:

```
mainList.add(list2);
list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```